# What are the characters for "qiu qiu", which means: "check this out"

Tags: phrase, word-requests

Regulars of this community might recognize me as the guy who asks for random phrases that I remember from my childhood, and this is another one that I can't find on Google Translate

The phrase is "Qiu Qiu" and I think it comes with the third tone (down/up) and then fifth tone (dot)

It should mean something like "Check this out" or "check me out"
Maybe I heard it in TV shows? or my kid cousins? like maybe my cousin would do a skateboard trick and say "qiuqiu" right before

I might have the pinyin totally wrong too.
Does anybody know what word I'm remembering?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Should be 瞅瞅, can be chou or qiu based on where you are in the northern China. This should be considered as a dialect rather than standard Mandarin.

Comment: i think this is the correct one, though the other user answered Qiao Qiao, and they both look, to have the same definition

Comment: but Chou Chou sounds way more familiar to me, and i'm pretty sure it's just a dialect that I also feel that qiu qiu sounds familiar too. My family is from northeast

Comment: @AO Yeah, 瞅 is used more in northeast Region. E.g. 你瞅啥？ 瞅你咋地！Qiu doesn't ring any bell to me, but chou evokes the character 瞅.

Comment: Didn't know your background so I made my guess based on "qiu qiu", which sounds like 瞧瞧 in Mandarin. If "chou chou" sounds way familiar to you then 瞅瞅 is the answer as it's a north east dialect from China

Answer (score 7):

My guess is:
瞧瞧
qiaoˊ qiaoˊ

When spoken in dialog you may hear qiaoˊ qiao˙, meaning they want you to take a look at something.

Here are [some examples](https://context.reverso.net/%E7%BF%BB%E8%AF%91/%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87-%E8%8B%B1%E8%AF%AD/%E7%9E%A7%E7%9E%A7).

Comment: But the asker mentioned the first character is third-tone; 瞧 is obviously not. It is strange!

Answer (score 1):

【瞧瞧 qiao qiao】  or 【瞅瞅 chou chou】？   【qiu qiu】→It's a regional dialect, not standard Pronunciation of Putonghua.

Answer (score 0):

Personally... I guess it may be `啾啾 jiujiu`(first tone). which represent the sound of birds. It stealthily reminds u to look somewhere or something. It's one kind of cuddly presentation.